# Docker image is way slower on Cloud Run than running local

Tags: node.js, docker, grpc, google-cloud-run

I have a Docker image that should convert .docx files to .pdf using `libreoffice-convert` node package. I would like to communicate to the service using gRPC.

When building and running the image locally, it takes about 5-6 seconds to execute and return a response, while instead when running on Cloud Run it takes at least a minute or more.

I've already tried to run the revision with CPU always allocated and at least 1 minimum instance, but nothing really changed in terms of response time.

I'm running the revision with 1 vCPU and 512MB of memory, request timeout is 300 secs and minimum requests per container is set to 80, using default execution environment.

How could I debug this issue? I've read about [running background activities](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#writing_effective_services) but making the CPU always allocated should have solved it, instead the timings are nearly identical.

Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add libreoffice
RUN apk add --no-cache msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig
RUN update-ms-fonts

# Google fonts
RUN wget https://github.com/google/fonts/archive/main.tar.gz -O gf.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf gf.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts && \
    find $PWD/fonts-main/ -name "*.ttf" -exec install -m644 {} /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/ \; || return 1 && \
    rm -f gf.tar.gz && \
    # Remove the extracted fonts directory
    rm -rf $PWD/fonts-main && \
    # Remove the following line if you're installing more applications after this RUN command and you have errors while installing them
    rm -rf /var/cache/* && \
    fc-cache -f

ENV DIR /app
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY . ${DIR}
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild grpc
ENV TZ Europe/Rome

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

index.js

```js
const grpc = require("grpc");
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const fs = require('fs');
const libre = require('libreoffice-convert');
const tmp = require('tmp');

const reportGenProto = protoLoader.loadSync("reportGen.proto");
const packageObject = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(reportGenProto);
const server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(packageObject.ReportGeneratorService.service, {
    Ping: async function (call, callback) {
        console.log("PONG");
        return callback(null, {
            pong: "pong"
        });
    },
    Generate: async function (call, callback) {
        try {
            const template = Buffer.from(call.request.templateFile, 'base64');

                const tmpFile = tmp.fileSync({ postfix: '.docx' });
                fs.writeFileSync(tmpFile.name, template);

                console.log('Saved temp file to', tmpFile.name);

                libre.convertAsync = require('util').promisify(libre.convert);

                const ext = '.pdf'

                console.log('Converting to', ext);

                let pdfBuf = await libre.convertAsync(doc, ext, undefined);

                console.log('Conversion complete');

                callback(null, {
                    content: Buffer.from(pdfBuf).toString('base64')
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            callback({ code: grpc.status.INTERNAL, message: err.toString() });
        }
    }
});

server.bind(
    `0.0.0.0:${process.env.PORT}`,
    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure()
);
console.log(`Server started on PORT ${process.env.PORT}`);
server.start();
```

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

service ReportGeneratorService {
  rpc Generate(GenerateForm) returns (Report){}
  rpc Ping (Empty) returns (Pong) {}
}

message Pong {
  string pong = 1;
}

message Report {
  string content = 1;
}

message GenerateForm {
  string templateFile = 1;
}

message Empty {}
```

Comment: Compare something comparable!! You have only 1 CPU on Cloud Run, and how many on your computer (hyperthreading included)? 4? 8? 20? In addition, what your CPU frequency? 3Ghz? 3.5Ghz? 4+Ghz? CPU in the cloud are Intel Xeon, limited to 2.4 or 2.8Ghz, maybe slighty more. Combine less CPU power and less CPU thread and you have your difference.

Comment: Is it that relevant? According to the logs, CPU utilization doesn't go beyond 40%. I'll give it a try anyway!

Comment: Nothing changed. 4 vCPU and 2GiB of memory, same response time. CPU utilization went to 5%. My laptop has a 6-core i7 clocked at 2.6GHz.

Comment: Does your application support multiple CPUs? Do you understand the difference between a vCPU (provided by the cloud) and a CPU core (provided by real processors)? Do you understand the difference between a physical CPU and a virtualized CPU? Seach Stack Overflow for these questions; I wrote some of the answers.

Comment: Cloud Run containers run atop virtualization layers too and this will have a performance hit but **not** as significant as your experience suggests. Have your tried profiling your code and comparing on-premises vs. Cloud Run? You could add simple timing, consider [Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler) [this works on Cloud Run although not documented and locally] and tracing networking calls e.g. [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace). It would be useful to understand where time is being spent and where this differs.

Comment: @DazWilkin comment leads me to an idea: try to deploy your service with the unsandboxed execution runtime on Cloud Run. For that, use the `--execution-environment=gen2` https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments

Comment: Using `gen2` didn't improve the situation. Gen2 benchmark (seconds) (117 78 61 78 57 74) - Default (58 62 43 63 96). I'm trying to profile using cloud profiler, but it's the first time for me. Anyway I don't think it will be useful, the bottleneck is in the `convertAsync` function. It uses `libreoffice` to convert the file and maybe there is something weird when launching app or commands from withing the code. Is it something the profiler can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the major bottleneck was the libreoffice conversion.

When converting with the `libreoffice --headless` command, the software will have to start, load into memory, and exit at every request. It looks like it's a heavy task for Cloud Run performances.

There are ready-to-use services like [Unoserver](https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver) and [Gotenberg](https://github.com/gotenberg/gotenberg) that somehow fix this issue by using LibreOffice's listener mode. For my use case this was enough and instead of doing everything I need from my gRPC server (which is doing other things other than converting to PDF), I've set up another Cloud Run instance with Gotenberg's Cloud Run image and I'll call its API from within my server.

Response time (including the other stuff my server is doing) is under 5 seconds now.